# swal is not rendered in context menu of an chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to use SweetAlert for alert box in my chrome extension. SweetAlert has to be shown when clicked in context menu. I have attached the sweetalert code in background scripts property inside manifest.json. I also used the css in content_scripts. Though default alert is showing but SweetAlert is not showing.

Here is the code for manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Detect Sentiment",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "A extension which can detect sentiment",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon128.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "16": "icon16.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon16.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["eventPage.js", "sweetalert.min.js"],
    "css": ["sweetalert.css"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "notifications", "contextMenus"]
}
```

Here is the code for eventPage.js

```
var contextMenuItem = {
  id: "detectSentiment",
  title: "Detect Sentiment",
  contexts: ["selection"],
};
chrome.contextMenus.create(contextMenuItem);

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function (clickData) {
  if (clickData.menuItemId == "detectSentiment" && clickData.selectionText) {
    console.log(clickData.selectionText);
    swal("Hello");
    alert(clickData.selectionText);
  }
});
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You can't use `css` inside `background` in manifest.json and you can't show swal there because this is an invisible background page. You need to inject a content script and show swal there.